# Laravel 8 If Statement which is better

Tags: laravel, if-statement

Want to know which solution is better in Laravel 8
I need to Display the name = company_name if it is not empty / OR =user_name   if company_name is empty OR = first_name + last_name  OR email

my code

```
     public function getDisplayName($email = false)
 {
     $name = $this->name??"";

 if(!empty($this->business_name) ){
     $name  = $this->business_name;
 }
 elseif(!empty($this->user_name) ){
     $name  = $this->user_name;
 }
 elseif (!empty($this->first_name) or !empty($this->last_name)) {
     $name = implode(' ', [$this->first_name, $this->last_name]);
 }

 elseif(!trim($name) and $email) $name = $this->email;
 else (empty($name)){
     $name = ' ';
 }
 return $name;
 }
```

will be better to use it for all cases or ifelse as in my code?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

> The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar
> for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with
> isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not null;
> otherwise it returns its second operand.

```
public function getDisplayName($email = false)
{
    return $this->business_name
        ?? $this->user_name
        ?? trim(implode(' ', [$this->first_name, $this->last_name]))
        ?? $this->email
        ?? ' ';
}
```

I leave you another [document link](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/whats-the-difference-between-null-coalescing-operator-and-ternary-operator-in-php) that will be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a `return` statement in an `if()` condition, you can use simple `if (...) { return ... }` syntax:

```php
public function getDisplayName($email = ' ') {
  if (!empty($this->business_name)) {
    return $this->business_name;
  }

  if (!empty($this->user_name)) {
    return $this->user_name;
  }

  return trim("{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}") ?? $email;
}
```

With this code, `business_name`, then `user_name`, then a combination of `first_name` and `last_name`, then `$email`, then finally `' '` will be returned. There isn't much use to assigning `$name` here if you're just going to return it at the end of the function, and you can simply set the final default as `$email = ' ';` and you're good.

Comment: @WillianKeller Thank you for the edit suggestion, but I'd prefer to keep indentation and brace placement to 2 spaces and same line respectively. This can easily be formatted if copy-pasted to a project, but I find it much easier to read on Stackoverflow when it is more condensed like this.

Comment: Thanks, the other solutions is much shorter and do the same. Thank you

Comment: @Yassin No problem! I try to avoid nested `??` or `? ... : ...` operators like that, but yes, same outcome with the answer above  Cheers!